# Appveyor + .net C# console/windows service application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, console-application, appveyor

I am trying to configure appveyor.yml file deploy .net console application to my server.

I had a look at appveyor doc on this, but it's unclear how to point to server etc.
https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/agent/

Following is part of my .yml file.

```
- provider: WebDeploy
  deploy_service: true
  service_executable: WindowService.exe
  service_name: WindowService.Test
  artifact: WindowService
  skip_dirs: \\Logs
```

Any sample .yml file for this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDeploy provider is suited to deploying WebDeploy packages. To deploy .NET Console application to the server you have control on, I would use [AppVeyor Deployment agent](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/agent/), and specifically [Windows Application](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/agent/#deploying-artifact-package-as-a-windows-application) part.